# How to fix NodeJS debugger command Injection vulnerability?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, security, devops

Through some security scans, I have found **NodeJS Debugger Command Injection** vulnerability on my server.

I have the recent stable version of node **v9.4.0**.

I need a solution to fix this Issue and also would like to know, How to reproduce and check the vulnerability.

Comment: Can you describe exactly what that vulnerability is and how it can be exploited? If you don't start your nodejs process with `--inspect` (which is something you should only do when actively debugging), then it does not listen for debugger commands.  Even when temporarily listening for debug commands, you can certainly block access to the debug port from the outside world.

Comment: You can trigger a nodejs process to start listening for debugging, but that requires signaling it with SIGUSR1 which obviously requires code running on the server with appropriately privileges.